# Glassfish-3.1.2 - Can I inject EntityManger into a stateless bean

Tags: concurrency, glassfish, stateless

I came across this blog below, concerning Servlets and injecting EJBs into them. 
The author is writing from a standards point-of-view.

http://tamanmohamed.blogspot.ie/2012/03/jpa-why-we-need-to-specifies-type-level.html
http://tamanmohamed.blogspot.ie/2012/03/jpa-thread-safety-when-injecting.html

"injecting EJB 3 stateful beans into servlet instance fields is not thread-safe. Along the same line, injecting EntityManager with @PersistenceContext into servlet instance variables is not thread-safe, either. EntityManager is just not designed to be thread-safe."

Anyhow, I am starting to get worried about the code I'm writing with a colleague in the
Glassfish-3.1.2  implementation.  See below.
I thought it was similar to code I've seen in Duke tutoring tutorial so it should be o.k.
(where FaceServlets call a stateless Request bean with @PersistnceContext EntityManager.)

However I guess I'm assuming the container-managed EntityManager is capable of coping
with lots of concurrent calls of a stateless bean called by many instances of servlets.

Is this a correct assumption for Glassfish-3.1.2 with an Oracle database ? It seems to work fine so far, but maybe it won't under heavy loads.

thanks in advance for any insights. Sorry I'm such a newby to this.
Fiona

```
Servlet
{
@EJB
private StatelessbeanBlah
:
}

@Stateless
StatelessBeanBlah
{
@PersistenceContext(unitname = "...")
private EntityManager em;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some confusion in your question, because thread-safety of EntityManager instances depend on whether you are using `Container-Managed Entity Managers` or `Application-Managed Entity Managers`. In the first case,

> an EntityManager instance’s persistence context is automatically
>   propagated by the container to all application components that use the
>   EntityManager instance within a single Java Transaction API (JTA)
>   transaction.
>
> ...
>
> By automatically propagating the persistence context, application components don’t need to pass references to EntityManager instances to each other in order to make changes within a single transaction. The Java EE container manages the lifecycle of container-managed entity managers.

(ref. [Managing Entities, Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqw.html))

Try to define a JTA-aware data source in your persistence.xml file, and see what happens. I am not keen in injecting a persistence context into a servlet, because when developing Java EE 6 web applications there is JSF, and you don't need to create your own servlets in most of the situations, and I am quite new to this technology, too. However, injecting a persistence context into a managed bean or an enterprise bean (like a Stateless EJB), with a JTA-aware data source, is absolutely fine and thread safe.

Comment: Thanks. So the code ->  Servlet calls Stateless Bean which has injected reference to EntityManager is fine, once the data source is "JTA-aware". Yes, I've checked in the persistence.xml and it is (has a transaction-type of JTA.) Great. Thanks again.

Comment: Be welcome! If you think the answer was useful, you can accept and / or upvote it.

Comment: I can't upvote it as it says I don't have enough reputation. sorry about that. I accepted it though!